# Python type hint enum member value

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'm trying to constrain an enum to have all member values of only one type. For example, I want

```
class MyTypedEnum(Enum):
    MEMBER_1= 1
    MEMBER_2= 2
    ...
```

to be an enum with only `int`s in its members' values.

Therefore, when I write `MyTypedEnum.MEMBER_X.value` into my IDE, it recognizes that the type is indeed `int`.

Edit: This is obviously a simple example with `int`, but I'd like to use any type in its place.

Comment: Isn't that what `enum.IntEnum` is for?

Comment: @chepner not exactly. honestly, `IntEnum` should probably only be used for backwards compatibility. Using `IntEnum` and `StrEnum` sorta defeats the entire purpose of enums.

Comment: @chepner Updated my answer to clarify that I want a generic solution and not something constrained to scalar types

Comment: If I do `reveal_type(MyTypedEnum.MEMBER_1.value)` `mypy` does indeed figure out that the type is `int`.  It also figures it out for any instance of `MyTypedEnum` -- presumably it takes the union of all the enum values to infer the type.  Can you switch your IDE to use a better typechecker?

Comment: @Samwise I'm using pylance in VS Code and it definitely can't infer the type. Even if it did, it looks like the python typing spec doesn't allow this, as per the first answer.

Comment: @DzeriMNE it's not so much that it doesn't allow it, it's just unspecified. `mypy` is the "unofficial official" static type checker for Python, and it handles it how one might *hope*, so this may be addressed in another PEP (that I haven't found) or maybe it's just a special feature of mypy for now

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well to be more clear, I wanted to get clever with it and use an enum in a sort of factory pattern, where a language construct would force the type of every value to inherit from a specific base class. As far as I understand, mypy might infer the type for a specific member, but nothing is stopping me from adding a member with another type of value. I'm guessing in that case the type checker will just infer `Any`

Comment: Correct.  For Enum to behave as you like, it'd have to be a `Generic`, so that you could specify (e.g.) an `Enum[int]` and any non-`int` value would be considered a type error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Python [typing spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) doesn't address this.

This is really going to depend on your IDE and static analysis tool. If I do:

```
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    bar: int = 1
    baz: int = 2

reveal_type(Foo.bar.value)
value: int = Foo.bar.value
```

Then `mypy` understands it just fine, and gives me:

```
(py39) Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juan$ mypy test.py
test.py:6: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

However, `pyright` gives me an error:

```
(py39) Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juan$ pyright test.py
Found 1 source file
/Users/juan/Coursera/test.py
  /Users/juan/Coursera/test.py:4:16 - error: Expression of type "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Literal[Foo.bar]"
    "Literal[1]" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[Foo.bar]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  /Users/juan/Coursera/test.py:5:16 - error: Expression of type "Literal[2]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Literal[Foo.baz]"
    "Literal[2]" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[Foo.baz]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
  /Users/juan/Coursera/test.py:6:13 - info: Type of "Foo.bar.value" is "int"
2 errors, 0 warnings, 1 info
Completed in 0.819sec
```

I imagine mypy is special-casing enums.

I found [this semi-related issue in the `pyright` github](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/1521).

And [here is a related PR from `mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/9443) where they added an inference feature for untyped enum values.